# Xcode 10.1 ViewController.h vs ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm having a problem with Xcode 10.1, where for a project I need to access something called the ViewController.swift, but whenever I try to open it I get something called ViewController.h (which is a lot of code which I cannot edit at all).

I'm a complete beginner (just trying it out), and I have no idea where to start. If any of you know how to get to ViewController.swift, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Xcode does not automatically generate a new `swift` file for you whenever you create a new ViewController. The `ViewController.h` file is simply a ViewController that is unnamed and cannot be programmed before a `swift` file is assigned to it.

You thus need to create your own `swift` file by doing this:

1. File --> New File (or just ⌘N) --> Cocoa Touch Class

[image]

2. Choose UIViewController in the drop down menu

[image]

3. Name your file (e.g. NameViewController)
4. Save it in your project directory (ideally save it inside your project folder, and choose the yellow-marked project folder as your group, and tick your app for targets (I have appended an image of my own project below for reference).

[image]

5. Now that you have your new CocoaTouchClass (it's actually just a swift file, but with pre-defined code for a ViewController or any other subclass you chose in the dropdown menu), click on the empty ViewController on your `Main.storyboard` file, go to your sidebar, and assign the class to your newly created ViewController file.

[image]

And now you have functioning `ViewController.swift` file which you can use.